# Syntax for functions that take in or return functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, syntax

I'm learning Haskell via Learn You a Haskell and I'm pretty sure he went over this at some point but I can't figure out where. Say I want to have a function return a pair, list of pairs, or general tuple. How is the type signature for this written? For example, for some given even number I want to return the list of unique pairs of primes that add up to it. I have a function `isPrime` that tells whether or not an `Int` is a prime.

```hs
pairs :: Int -> [(Int a, Int b)]
pairs n
  | n < 4 = []
  | odd n = []
  | otherwise = [(a, b) | a < b, isPrime a, isPrime b, a+b == 1]
```

When I try to compile this, I get the error saying "Int has too few arguments." So I tried the following syntax instead:

```hs
pairs :: Int -> [((Int a), (Int b))]
```

But I got the same error. So in general how does typesetting functions involving pairs work?

Comment: What two primes will add up to 1?

Comment: See http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#kinds-and-some-type-foo

Comment: @chepner 3 and -2, naturally.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem isn't one of formatting. `Int a` and `Int b` are ill-kinded. `Int` can't be applied because it isn't a (type-level) function. You just want `Int -> [(Int, Int)]`.